# get the request from server (Python, websocket, treading)

Tags: python, websocket, telegram-bot, python-multithreading

I heve a small problem.
I have a telegram bot, witch must connects to server using websocket technology, and will get the request from server using treading technology.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Для начала зарегистрируйся:')
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '1) Введи свой номер СНИЛС:')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_SNILS)
    elif message.text == '/f':
        test_keyboard(message)
    elif message.text == '/send':
        connect_to_back.send_message('WOW', server)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напиши /start')
```

When you write "/send" to my bot, it will call function `connect_to_back.send_message` with parameter `message`.

```
def send_message(message: str, server: tuple):
    global shutdown
    shutdown = False
    host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    port = 0
    recv_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    recv_server.bind((host, port))
    recv_server.setblocking(0)
    rT = threading.Thread(target=receving, args=("RecvThread", recv_server))
    rT.start()

    send = False
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            if not send:
                if message != "":
                    recv_server.sendto("[bot connected]".encode("utf-8"), server)
                    recv_server.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)
                    send = True
                time.sleep(0.2)
        except:
            shutdown = True
            recv_server.sendto("[bot disconnected]".encode("utf-8"), server)

    rT.join()
    recv_server.close()
```

This function works inextricably with the function `receving`.

```
def receving(name, sock):
    global shutdown
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                decoded_data = data.decode("utf-8")
                print(decoded_data)
                if decoded_data == 'successfully':
                    shutdown = True
                time.sleep(0.2)
        except:
            pass
```

Function `send_message` will connect to server and send message "WOW". Then it waits the server answer. If server answer is "successfully", the program will be stop.
Now my question: How can bot get message "successfully" from function `receving`? So that later bot will send word "successfully" to user in telegram chat.
all the code I described earlier works correctly. I just don't know how to pull out the value of a variable `decoded_data` from function `receving`. And return it to the same place where I called the function `send_message`.

Now I don't even know how to correctly formulate a question for Google So I'm asking this question here.